# IE7 on XP not listening to Stylesheet, though IE8 Compat mode on 7 does

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, windows-xp

**UPDATE:**  *I couldn't tell you what changed to save my life, but suddenly it's working...  Thank you everyone for your help.*

I have a default CSS style sheet, an IE specific stylesheet, and a IE7 specific stylesheet.

On Windows 7 in IE8 the IE sheet is loaded, and in IE8 Compatibility mode the IE7 sheet is loaded.

On Windows XP in IE7, neither stylesheet is loaded, thus breaking (or rather, not fixing) my layout.  This brings up a couple of questions...

1. Does IE7 on XP use different language to call browser specific style sheets?  Was there a different standard for calling sheets when it was made?
   This is what I have currently:

   ```
   <!--[if IE]>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ieprocessstyle.css" />
   <![endif]-->

   <!--[if IE 7]>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7processstyle.css">
   <![endif]-->
   ```
2. Could it be caused by some bug or error on the machine I'm using?  Could different machines with XP and IE7 act differently?

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me.  The site is for a large corporation and they forced me to go live already so I'm just waiting to get a call from the Big Bad Angry Voodoo Daddy....

Comment: It's an internal proprietary intranet site :/

Comment: Do they load in xp-ie7 without the if-conditions?

Comment: Yes they do.  But as soon as the same syntax is inside the IF-condition, it doesn't load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special syntax for IE7, here is a conditional set that works in 6, 7 and 8:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link href="/_ui/css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /><![endif]--> 
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link href="/_ui/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /><![endif]--> 
<!--[if lte IE 6]><link href="/_ui/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /><![endif]-->
```

Here is a code reference for IE conditionals:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: I'm using this exact code (with the correct path) and still having no luck... I'm stumped..

Comment: @Caleb, you say this exact code, hopefully not copied and pasted without altering the path to be correct ;)

Comment: Yeah I fixed the path, but good question.  I wouldn't put it past me  :P

Comment: I don't know what changed, but it's all good now.  Thank you Marcy and everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

So first should load in all IE versions and second should, in addition to first, be loaded for IE 7 right ?

Nothing wrong with the syntax.. (*you could correctly close the tag at the end in the IE7 version `/>`*), and nothing different in syntax between versions.. the problem must lie elsewhere..

Comment: Correct.  I'll close out the tags for good measure, but I agree, the problem must be in something I haven't found... Thanks for the tip though